# how to install dependencies of a Laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to Laravel, I have got to work on an existing project that is located on a server. I am able to access the source code through the FileZilla. The size of the whole project on the server is more than 6 GB. I know that I shouldn't download the whole project but the main folder and run `composer install` command to install all the dependencies specified in the vendor/composer folder. but I am not able to figure out the structure of the project and which part I need to download in order to run the `composer install` command and get the project running locally on my machine. Below is the project structure on the server.
[image]

I can right-click on a node and select download. which folder is the main project? that I assume it should only has the main files and the composer.json file where all deps are specified in it?

Comment: The folder that _contains_ the composer.json file is generally the one that you want to download. Alternatively, if your project is in source control such as git, it is possible that you can just clone that repo directly and it probably won't include uploaded assets, which may or may not work depending on what you need to work on.

Comment: That doesn't look like a Laravel app's folders. There's no `plugins` or `templates` folder in Laravel; you're also missing a `vendor` and `resources` and several other folders. `composer install` utilizes a file called `composer.json` (and possibly `composer.lock)`.

Comment: Have you downloaded the laravel starter project? this does not look like laravel

Answer (score 1):

you may need to download the whole project, since there are Controllers, Migrations, resources, etc.